# How may I test the type of a DataGridViewCell?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I tried to test whether myDataGridViewCell is a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell

```
if(myDataGridViewCell.ValueType is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) ...
```

but this gives the warning:

> The given expression is never of the provided 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxCell') type

How can you test the type of a DataGridViewCell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ValueType` is the type of the data values that the cell holds. That's not what you want.

To test the type of the cell itslelf, just do:

```
if (myDataGridViewCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
 ...
```

(will be true for `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` and all subtypes)

or

```
if (myDataGridViewCheckBoxCell != null &&
    myDataGridViewCheckBoxCell.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxCell))
    ...
```

(will be true for `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` only).

Answer (score 2):

```
if (myDataGridViewCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
```

Your code is checking whether the value of the [`ValueType` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.valuetype.aspx) is convertible to `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`.
Since `ValueType` always holds a `System.Type` instance, it's never a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`, so the compiler gives you a warning.